# Can we get support for latin characthers in tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Characters like 'ç' and 'ã' are removed from tags. Is this intentional? It doesn't really add much value, but it's weird to see them without the diacritics.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange’s tag system can be tweaked per-site.

By default, on most sites, it allows only

- the basic Latin alphabet with no diacritics,
- numbers,
- hyphens.

However, on [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/), [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/), and [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), diacritics are allowed. And on [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) and [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) tags can use the Cyrillic alphabet.

I imagine that tags with diacritics will be enabled here soon.

Comment: It is really strange to see Portuguese tags without diacritics. They miss a lot and sometimes, makes, e.g., written Portuguese language weirder than it is now, with such ridiculous, at least for me, spelling reform.

Comment: It is really very strange to see Portuguese tags without diacritics. It makes  written Portuguese language much weirder than it is now, with this ridiculous spelling reform, at least for me.

Comment: @tucasilvapontes11584. This was tagged "status completed" on [the 14th of July, last year](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/3/revisions). So tags with diacritics are now allowed. If you still see tags without diacritics, you may want to edit them (or post a new question on Meta to point it out).

Comment: Thank you for the information.